# How to replicate "X days posted ago"

Tags: templating

I'm trying to build my blog functionality with craft, and struggling to get the functionality of showing "when" that post was created.

Is it possible to do the following:

Posted X days ago,
Posted x Weeks ago,
Posted x Months ago,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Straight Up Craft has a solid list of plugins.

Nice time is most likely the one you are looking for.

http://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/nice-time

Comment: Gold Jerry! Gold!