# date_modify relative time

Tags: datetime

I'd like to reopen [this question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/5365/how-to-replicate-x-days-posted-ago):

The answer was a plugin called [Nice Time](https://github.com/pvledoux/blocks-nicetime)

But This plugin is depricated and the creator stats that this functionality is acheivable via the `date_modify` filter.

Yes okay, but how?

I have a event archive where I want to show "This event happend `xy` days ago".

There is a [time_diff](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/date.html) filter in twig. But it seems as if this is not activated in craft.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the `diff` method to get the number of days between two dates. So for example:

```
{{ date(entry.dateCreated|date('c')).diff(now).days }} days ago
```

In my example between today (using `now`) and the `entry.dateCreated`.

There is a explanation as to why you need to wrap the first date in the `date` filter [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/9759/142), which is where I got the answer from!

Comment: How would I print seconds or hours? `.seconds` does nothing?

Comment: Instead of `.days`, use `.format`, and then use one of the format chars listed [here](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php). So for example to get months use `.format('%m')`.

Answer (score 3):

I have a plugin that adds the time_diff Twig filter to Craft:

https://github.com/mildlygeeky/craft-timediff

There is one possible issue (in either PHP or Craft) around DST, and I will add that to the README.

Comment: Unfortunately that ads a suffix "days ago" which is bad for a german Site :)

Comment: Hi @KSPR - just added a new version that includes an array option with translated strings where possible, and you could then use the raw output to format the diff however you'd like. :)

Comment: Nice :) I'll check it out.